# Single-Phase to Three Phase Cycloconverter

Tags: frequency, converter, three-phase, conversion, single-phase

When my classmate report about cycloconverters. He discussed about different classifications and types of cycloconverters. He also discussed how Single-phase to Single-Phase Cycloconverters operate. But when he approached Three-Phase to Single-Phase and Three-Phase to Three-Phase Cycloconverter's operations, he discussed it not very well leading to a lot of confusions. Almost all of the answers to those confusions was answered through Internet except one:

> > Is there any Single-Phase to Three-Phase Cycloconverter existing? How does it operate?

Answer (score 1):

If there are single-phase-to-single-phase cyclo-converters then using three together (control phased at 120 degrees) will produce a 3 phase device. The IEEE reports that they have been studied [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/166735).

The main difficulty is that with a single phase input (at say 50Hz) you can't create a 3 ph output at 50Hz - this means that they are likely to have applications in specialist slow speed motors areas and this may be a small area of the market and hard to find data on.